# CryptoJs как реализовать на php

Tags: php, javascript, cryptojs

Есть строчка на js, с использованием библиотеки [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/):

```
var randomNumberMd5 = CryptoJS.MD5(randomNumber).toString().toUpperCase();
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(randomNumberMd5);
```

как ее можно реализовать на php?

Comment: Для начала, неплохо было бы указать ссылку на библиотеку, о которой идет речь

Comment: @DmitriySimushev http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Crypto-JS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) реализует на JS *стандартные* алгоритмы шифрования. Т.е. они же существуют и для php. В документации описаны методы библиотеки. Разберитесь, что делают ваши две строки, и это станет легко повторить на php.

Напр. первая строка [вычисляет MD5 хэш](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#MD5) от переменной `randomNumber`, получает его как текстовую строку и переводит в верхний регистр.

На php для этого есть ф-и [`md5()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.md5.php) и [`strtoupper()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtoupper.php).

Вторая строка [преобразует](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Encoders) переданный параметр в WordArray – массив 32-битных слов в кодировке UTF8. В вашей php-реализации, возможно, это и не потребуется.